# Flask-SQLAlchemy returns stale data when queried from Celery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, celery

I have a pretty big Flask app and would like to add Celery to it. The issue is that when the Celery task queries the app's database (postgresql) it returns stale (old) data. I've looked for suggestions but could not find any other than doing a `db.session.commit()` before the query. That seems a bit hacky to me and I'm also concerned if the Flask app would start to get stale data also.

I've read in some forums that Flask-SQLAlchemy already handles these cases but it seems it doesn't in my case. Is there any way to fix this without a whole lot of refactoring of the existing app?

I'm using:

- Flask-SQLAlchemy v2.5.1
- Celery v5.2.7

```
import ssl
from copy import deepcopy

from celery import Celery


def make_celery(app):

    celery = Celery(app.import_name)


    ssl_config = {
        "ca_certs": app.config["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"],
        "cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
    }

    celery.config_from_object(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from .celery import make_celery

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
app.config.from_object(os.getenv("CONFIG_OBJECT", "app.config.ProductionConfig"))
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

jwt = JWTManager(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
db.init_app(app)


celery = make_celery(app)
```

Comment: Guessing a bit here, but assuming celery and the flask request are using different sessions, and that the stale data should be updated in the request, you might need to delay starting the celery task until the flask request has completed (specifically, until its session has committed).

Comment: The issue is not that the data in not saved in the DB, but that the SQLAlchemy session object stores the data in memory. Only after I do a `db.session.commit()` do I get the new data. For example: something triggers a celery task and in that task there is a function that tells a third system to fetch some data. That system then returns the required data to the Flask app (api) and the app stores it in the db. The Celery task meanwhile has a loop in which it checks for the new data (like 1x a second). Without a `db.session.commit()` it won't get the new data even though it is returned in 200ms

Comment: The querying in a loop pattern doesn't play well with [transaction isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)), that's why you need to commit each time.

Comment: After reading up a bit the default isolation level for PostgreSQL is `Read commited` . My case is `non-repeatable read` where a another transaction updates the data in between the reads. Under the `Read commited` isolation level the read transaction [should return the updated value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Non-repeatable_reads). Am I missing something?

Comment: It certainly should work, if both connections are using `READ COMMITTED`. But it's hard to say more without a [mre].

Comment: After some investigation and testing I concluded that it was not due to transaction isolation. When tested by doing a raw sql squery with the `db.execute()` and doing a Flask-SQLalchemy `object.query.get()`. The raw query returned new data, while SQLAlchemy returned the stale data. The solution was a `db.session.close()` to close the session and query the object again. Thank you every one for your help.